# Долой веб админку для сайта

Tags: администрирование, админка

Всем привет! Появился вариант при разработке сайта исключить web админку заменив ее специальной программой работающей с api сайта. Как я считаю это будет намного безопаснее веб админки так как чтоб получить доступ надо скачать ПО, знать лог и пасс + 2х факторная авторизация НУ или же на угад тыкаться в api сайта. В случае с веб админкой достаточно найти url который ведет на авторизацию и начинать взлом =)

Возможно, у вас есть опыт в данном направлении, буду рад если поделитесь своими соображениями и информацией!

Comment: И двухфакторной авторизации у веб-админки конечно быть не может.

Comment: конечно может быть, просто найти url для перехода к авторизации гораздо проще чем рандомно тыкаться в api сайта либо же скачать программу неизвестно откуда ( которая есть у админа ) и даже скачав ее нужны данные конекта, логина, пароля, и + 2х факторной авторизации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что мешает просто прикрутить двухфакторную авторизацию к админке + установить лимит попыток входа?

ПО нужно будет держать на всех устройствах, где может понадобиться доступ к админке. Устройства могут иметь разную ОС, разную архитектуру... Мне кажется, это вызовет больше проблем, чем прибавит в безопасности...

В конце концов, и веб-админку можно разместить на другом домене или неявном поддомене.

Comment: просто из расчета большей функциональности, через ПО более эффективно обрабатывать данные, считывать артикулы, и использовать другие устройства ввода. Насчет совместимости ПО с платформой... тут есть нюансы, да

Comment: Меня больше беспокоит не убавится безопасность используя ПО?

Comment: По сути, ПО всё равно будет авторизовываться на сайте. Так что безопасность будет на одинаковом уровне. И, кстати, ещё момент: Допилив новую фичу в API, нужно будет её интегрировать в ваше ПО, под каждую ось. А потом обновить на каждом устройстве...

Comment: ну аналогичная ситуация с самой админкой. Добавив фичу в api нужно будет обновить админку. Накладка с обновление разве что, с платформой проблем нет так как планируется только Windows. И то, обновление ПО можно автоматизировать

Comment: Я на одном проекте сделал админку по неинтуитивному адресу (что-то вроде /hfgjsfstjhcdk/), добавил страницу `/wp-login` (проект не на вордпрессе), и обработчик формы просто показывает ошибку с неправильным паролем. Судя по логам, мамкины хакеры пытаются взломать мой вордпресс, а вот на реальную админку ещё никто не покушался.

Comment: интересный вариант =)